# Understanding stanag 4609 klv format

Tags: stream, metadata, stanag

I am trying to parse a stanag 4609 klv stream from external camera.

For beginning, I am trying to figure the altitude value received in stream.

By stanag 4609 documentation,  the value is 2 - bytes long, in feet, represented as float.

I know that the camera altitude is approximately 39.8 meters, but I can't interpret the 2 - bytes I receive to that value (in feet).
The 2 bytes I received are {12,23}.

How can I interpret it in the correct way?

Comment: check this code to parse all STANAG tags https://github.com/paretech/klvdata

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In STANAG 4609 KLV, floating point values are encoded as integers. You can check [MISB ST0601](http://www.gwg.nga.mil/misb/docs/standards/ST0601.8.pdf) for the particular data element you're interested in. It will give you the conversion formula to convert the 2-byte integer into the correct floating point value.

Assuming you're referring to the `Sensor True Altitude` (tag 15), the conversion formula is `(19900/65535) * int_value - 900`.

Applying this to your data:

1. Interpret the bytes [12, 23] ([0x0C, 0x17] in hexadecimal) as an integer. 0xC17 is equal to 3095.
2. Apply the formula. `(19900/65535) * 3095 - 900` = 39.81 meters